# How to insert an Item with content type Folder

Tags: 2007, content-type

I have a custom list with a custom content type inherited from the Folder content type.

When I insert a new item in the list I do it like this:

```
newItem["Name"] = "New Folder";
newItem["Content Type"] = "Package";
newItem.Update();
```

The item is inserted but I found that its title is something like **51_.000** and if I insert another item the title is **52_.000** and so on.

Is there something wrong with this code? If so, how do I insert a folder with the title properly?

Answer (score 1):

The Title field is not the same as the Name field. Try updating the Title field to the desired value.

Comment: I already did that and still not working

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the list in something like a Meeting Workspace.

You need to set the list to create Series items first.

This is the setting you need to set for the List. Ensure you do this at creation time, as you cannot undo it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.multipledatalist.aspx

Comment: Sorry but the list is not in a meeting workspace, it is a custom list in a Team site